# Cannot connect to DHCP server running on the rpi

Tags: dhcp

I'm trying to set up my raspberry pi as a VPN Gateway following this tutorial:
http://blog.frd.mn/raspberry-pi-vpn-gateway/

I'm using another WLAN-adapter but that shouldn't matter. So at the end I get all the services (hostapde, isc-dhcp-server, and openvpn) to run but I cannot connect to the DHCP. When I try to connect my Android Phone to the new WLAN it just stops trying at some point and connects to my original WLAN. When I connect my Windows-Computer to the new WLAN it tells me that the connection is restricted and when I check, I can see that I don't have an IP-adress from the DHCP.

When I check /var/log/syslog, I get:

```
Dec 22 16:56:42 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3421.603270] ---[ end trace e7db3c361613ef28 ]---
Dec 22 16:56:47 rpi-livingroom dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from fc:c2:de:9f:6e:fe (android-29649d76dedea826) via wlan0
Dec 22 16:56:47 rpi-livingroom dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.18.10 to fc:c2:de:9f:6e:fe (android-29649d76dedea826) via wlan0
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom hostapd: wlan0: STA fc:c2:de:9f:6e:fe IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.693154] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.693324] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 2150 at net/mac80211/ieee80211_i.h:813 ieee80211_tdls_mgmt+0xa38/0xa48 [mac80211]()
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.693341] Modules linked in: tun 8021q garp stp llc ipt_MASQUERADE iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat ipt_REJECT xt_comment nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack nf_conntrack iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables snd_bcm2835 arc4 snd_usb_audio snd_hwdep snd_usbmidi_lib snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event rt2800usb snd_soc_bcm2708_i2s rt2800lib crc_ccitt regmap_mmio rt2x00usb rt2x00lib snd_soc_core regmap_spi snd_rawmidi snd_pcm_dmaengine mac80211 joydev snd_pcm snd_page_alloc regmap_i2c snd_compress snd_seq cfg80211 snd_timer rfkill snd_seq_device snd
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.693517] CPU: 0 PID: 2150 Comm: hostapd Tainted: G        W    3.12.26-rpi-aufs #1
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.693587] [<c00147d8>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf0) from [<c0011b9c>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.693627] [<c0011b9c>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14) from [<c001fa48>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x68/0x88)
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.693730] [<c001fa48>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x68/0x88) from [<c001fa84>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x1c/0x24)
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.693831] [<c001fa84>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x1c/0x24) from [<bf0a4058>] (ieee80211_tdls_mgmt+0xa38/0xa48 [mac80211])
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.693965] [<bf0a4058>] (ieee80211_tdls_mgmt+0xa38/0xa48 [mac80211]) from [<bf0a4204>] (ieee80211_change_station+0x19c/0x308 [mac80211])
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.694106] [<bf0a4204>] (ieee80211_change_station+0x19c/0x308 [mac80211]) from [<bf035fb4>] (nl80211_set_station+0x1c0/0x258 [cfg80211])
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.694338] [<bf035fb4>] (nl80211_set_station+0x1c0/0x258 [cfg80211]) from [<c03df468>] (genl_rcv_msg+0x1fc/0x328)
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.694385] [<c03df468>] (genl_rcv_msg+0x1fc/0x328) from [<c03de890>] (netlink_rcv_skb+0xbc/0xd8)
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.694418] [<c03de890>] (netlink_rcv_skb+0xbc/0xd8) from [<c03deb48>] (genl_rcv+0x20/0x34)
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.694448] [<c03deb48>] (genl_rcv+0x20/0x34) from [<c03de280>] (netlink_unicast+0x158/0x1b4)
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.694476] [<c03de280>] (netlink_unicast+0x158/0x1b4) from [<c03de4d0>] (netlink_sendmsg+0x1f4/0x35c)
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.694513] [<c03de4d0>] (netlink_sendmsg+0x1f4/0x35c) from [<c03a2464>] (sock_sendmsg+0x98/0xb8)
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.694542] [<c03a2464>] (sock_sendmsg+0x98/0xb8) from [<c03a2804>] (___sys_sendmsg+0x2a0/0x2b8)
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.694575] [<c03a2804>] (___sys_sendmsg+0x2a0/0x2b8) from [<c03a4334>] (__sys_sendmsg+0x3c/0x68)
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.694610] [<c03a4334>] (__sys_sendmsg+0x3c/0x68) from [<c000e3a0>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
Dec 22 16:56:49 rpi-livingroom kernel: [ 3428.694627] ---[ end trace e7db3c361613ef29 ]---
Dec 22 16:56:50 rpi-livingroom hostapd: wlan0: STA fc:c2:de:9f:6e:fe IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to inactivity
```

I do not fully understand this, but it seems to me that there is a request for an IP and the server hands one out. But why is my client not connected to the network, then?

My /etc/network/interfaces is:

```
# Static network configuration handled by Berryboot
iface eth0 inet manual

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.168.18.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0

up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

At the end of /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf I have the lines:

```
subnet 192.168.18.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.168.18.10 192.168.18.50;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.18.255;
        option routers 192.168.18.1;
        default-lease-time 600;
        max-lease-time 7200;
#       option domain-name "local";
#       option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}
```

Can anyone tell me, what I could check next?

EDIT:
So it looks like it has something to do with the iptables. I removed the rules from the tutorial above and instead used the ones from here: http://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point.pdf

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Now, I can use the raspberry pi as a DHCP server and have internet connection on the connected devices. Unfortunately I cannot use openvpn on the pi with this setup, as the rules for iptables above seem not to work once openvpn is running.

Answer (score 1):

**Setting up the raspberry pi as gateway for an openvpn-connection:**

(I know this doesn't exactly answer my original question but it solved the problem for me and I thought maybe someone else is having the same problem.)

I think I have it working now. I followed [this guide](http://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point.pdf) to set up the raspberry pi as a bridge (instead of an access point). I then set up openvpn like described [here](http://blog.frd.mn/raspberry-pi-vpn-gateway/).

After that I added the iptables-rules:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```